# WordPress/PHP get all navigation links

Tags: php, wordpress, object, navigation, return

I am working on a small plugin and am wondering how can I get all links in primary navigation? Wondering if it's possible without knowing the name or slug of the menu in a particular theme.

Below I was trying to get all menu links and return them in a script tag but it didn't work out too well. It ended up returning a bunch of metadata and on one site it broke the site completely.

For now, the script tag is only for testing purposes, where I am going to use the navigation links in an unordered list later on.

````
function get_nav_menu_items_by_location( $location, $args = [] ) {
    ?>
<script type = "application/ld+json" alt="hejtest" >
<?
    // Get all locations
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
 
    // Get object id by location
    $object = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[$location] );
 
    // Get menu items by menu name
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $object->name, $args );
    
   // Return menu post objects
    return $menu_items;
?>
</script>
<?
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'get_nav_menu_items_by_location');
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "return" data from PHP to JS. The `return` keyword tells *PHP* that you've finished the `get_nav_menu_items_by_location` function, and to give that value to *the calling PHP code*.

To run JavaScript, you need to *output* some code that the browser will then *execute* when it receives the HTML.

If you want to output some data in a way that's easy for JS to read, you can abuse the fact that JSON format is valid JS code, and write `echo json_encode($menu_items);`. You also need to output code to assign it to a variable, or pass it to a function.

If the function you're writing is expected to *return* some HTML, you don't want to use `echo`, and also don't want to use `?>`. Instead, you want to build up a PHP string containing the HTML and return that.

So you might end up with this:

```php
function get_nav_menu_items_by_location( $location, $args = [] ) {
    $html = '<script type="application/ld+json" alt="hejtest">';

    // Get all locations
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
 
    // Get object id by location
    $object = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[$location] );
 
    // Get menu items by menu name
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $object->name, $args );
    
    $html .= "var my_menu_items = " . json_encode($menu_items) . ";";

    $html .= "</script>";

    return $html;
}
add_action('wp_head', 'get_nav_menu_items_by_location');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @IMSoP! That makes perfect sense. My only problem is that my_menu_items keeps returning false for some reason. I have edited a bit in my code and updated the question with my current code I came up with, with the help of your answer.

Comment: @TurboTobias I've rolled back your edit. If you have a different problem in the same code, or a new version of your code, ask a new question. This isn't a forum, and doesn't work very well if you "move the goalposts" so that people have to keep editing their answers to match.

Comment: oh... Ok. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll create a new question :)